# query json data in postgres 9.3

Tags: json, postgresql, psql

I have read the questions regarding json columns and apparently just not understanding.

Here is excerpt of a postgresql query using a json column  My problem is:

I can query a top level for data ( referralReasons )
But when I try to query data from a lower level ( TASCReferral .... "referralComments" I get blank results
I realize I am not writing the query correctly, but I cannot find understandable instructions on  how.

Thanks for any help

Below this is the json for reference

-------------- query ---------------------------

```
 SELECT 
  groups.name AS group, 
  (to_char (referrals."referraldate", 'MM/DD/YY'))AS DateReferred,
  referrals."referral_age",
  referrals."name" AS Offender,
  referrals.po_name AS Officer,
 -- referrals.jsondata->'referralReasons' AS po_comment,
 referrals.jsondata->'referralComments' AS po_comment,
 referrals.visibility_flag

FROM
groups, referrals
WHERE .........
```

--------- json data taken from   referrals.jsondata  column---------

```
{
    "pendingCharges": [],
    "residence": {
        "zip": "12345",
        "phone": "(252)555-1212",
        "county": "BEAUFORT",
        "street": "1313 MOCKING BIRD LN",
        "state": "NC",
        "city": "SOMETOWN"
    },
    "dates": {
        "referralDate": "2015-12-08",
        "convictionDate": "2011-10-20",
        "birthDate": "1909-09-16"
    },
    "html": {
        "zrud_group": "TEST",
        "zzud_referral": "15AC82D5-E743-40A2-8553-ER765DKOPIT11"
    },
    "TASCReferral": {
        "referralKey": "ABCD-EFG-HITK",
        "phone": {},
        "charges": "LARCENY",
        "conviction": "019 years 11 months 10 days",
        "officerName": "BUTLER, SMEDLEY",
        "DrugTestSummaryLink": "https.GOHERE.COM",
        "referralComments": "Appointment Date: Week of 12/08/2015   -- This offender is an out of state case.  He tested positive today for cocaine.",
        "officerEmail": "MEANJOE@PROBATION.COM",
        "supervisionLevel": "L3",
        "gangName": " ",
        "RNASummaryLink": "https://GOTHERE.COM",
        "punishmentType": "NON-N.C. OFF.",
        "OPUSID": "9876543",
        "docketNumber": "CR00000000",
        "officerPhone": "(252)666-8888",
        "name": "CLIENT TEST",
        "age": "18",
        "gangAffiliated": "false",
        "countyOfConviction": "OTHER",
        "gender": "Male",
        "supervisionType": "PRO: PROBATION",
        "TASCOffice": "TESTOFFICE"
    },
    "referralReasons": [
        "Court-Ordered Assessment",
        "Baseline Admission or Positive Drug Screen",
        "Offender admits to using/positive for: cocaine - Date of last use: 10/09/2015"
    ]
```

Comment: json is not valid - add closing `}`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have your `data` column with JSON, you can use `->` (get JSON object field) and `->>` (get JSON field as TEXT) to go over json structure, relevant documentation is [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html):

```
SELECT jt.data->'TASCReferral'->>'referralComments' 
FROM json_test jt;
```

Comment: Dmitry -  Thanks so much!  I had the information a year of so ago, and could not find it.  Mr google was little help.  I just ran the query with your changes and it worked great.  Now I need to re-create a "How-Do-I" doc and put in safe place.  Again, you are a life saver!